# So can I use input data in pd.date_range?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I found out Pandas date_range is very useful.

Here is my question,

```
a=input("'yyyy-mm-dd': ")
b=input("'yyyy-mm-dd': ")
df2 = df.pd.date_range[a,b]
```

Can I do something like this?
If I can't, is there any way I can use two input dates as the start and the end of range by using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get user input as dates and feed that to `pd.date_range`, yes, but with some adjustments:

The `pd.date_range()` method uses parentheses, not quotes ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)). So to use the user specified `a` and `b` in that method you'd write:

```
user_date_range = pd.date_range(start=a,end=b)
```

Dataframe objects don't have a `pd` or `date_range` attribute, so you can't prefix that method with your dataframe `df`.

Also, `pd.date_range()` returns "fixed frequency DatetimeIndex", not a dataframe itself. The default time-step from the start date to the end date is `freq='D'`, which means the range is created by creating a date range with daily frequency. You can instead specify number of periods, which automatically creates evenly spaced intervals.

Comment: Good answer.  @ThomasKavanagh  +1

Comment: Ty! What I actually want a part of a dataframe. Which is made with temperature based on my country. So how can I get dataframe instead of fixed dataindex? Is that also worked by 'date_range'?

Comment: @JeeWoong Lee - I'm having trouble visualizing what you're after. It might help to provide an example, even with dummy data, of what you hope to end up with. Are you hoping to retrieve the individual dates in the range as a single row? From the example you gave, that would produce a dataframe with at most 1 rows.